# jQuery prettyPhoto: How to pass additional GET parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

```
<a href="page.html?iframe=true&amp;width=700&amp;height=100%&amp;myVar=text" rel="prettyPhoto">Click Me</a>
```

In js script:

```
$('a[rel*=prettyPhoto]').prettyPhoto({
        keyboard_shortcuts: false,
        social_tools: false,
        deeplinking: false
    });
```

And in page.html I cannot access myVar. Help?

- Found similar question [here](http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/2328/passing-more-parameters-in-the-iframe-url-prettyphoto/p1), but it's not answered either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION FOUND**: The url parameters you want to pass should be before "iframe" variable. Eg.:

```
page.html?myVar=text&iframe=true&width=700&height=100%
```